# How to Click a Link on a webpage using external VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to do the following by using VBScript
Open IE

Navigate to a page - Wait for IE to load - Click on a hyperlink

I have written a below code but it is failing

```
Dim IE
Dim Helem

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "www.mypage.com"

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("helpDesk").Click
```

But it always keeps giving the below error

The interface is unknown or Unspecified error etc

Comment: Please specify the line which gives an error. 8 or 12?

Comment: Error on line 12, Char 1
Error: Object required: 'Document.GetElementByID(...)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lot of struggling i found out what the issue is
IE.Document.getElementById("helpDesk").Click

should be

IE.document.getElementById("helpDesk").Click

'd' is lowercase in the Document

Comment: This can not be the cause of the error, since vbscript is not case sensitive.

Comment: I read somewhere that it is IE browser version related. However after changing it i got it resolved

Comment: I have to confess you are right. I faced a fact that `iHeight = .Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth` gives an error, but `iHeight = .Document.ParentWindow.screen.AvailWidth` works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Next script should be error-free (nothing more to say don't knowing the `"helpDesk"` element further attributes):

```
Dim IE
Dim Helem

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "www.mypage.com"

While IE.Busy
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Wend

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

IE.Document.getElementById("helpDesk").Click()
```

Note the `Busy` property gets a (boolean) value that indicates whether the object is engaged in a navigation or downloading operation.

Note the `click()` method simulates a mouse-click on an element; this method can be used to execute a click on an element as if the user manually clicked on it.

Note next `readyState` property enumeration (constant names are not being intrinsic in `VBScript`):

- `READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED ​` (0) The object has been created, but not initialized (the open method has not been called).
- `READYSTATE_LOADING       ​` (1) A request has been opened, but the send method has not been called.
- `READYSTATE_LOADED        ​` (2) The send method has been called. No data is available yet.
- `READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE   ​` (3) Some data has been received; however, responseText is not available.
- `READYSTATE_COMPLETE      ​` (4) All the data has been received.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. When i run this for Gmail page it work fine.. but when i change the URL to my company's URL, before loading the page completely the error message occurs. Is there a way to know if the page is fully loaded?

Comment: Although testing both `Busy` and `ReadyState` properties should be sufficient, you could add some `WScript.Sleep` before `click()`

Answer (score 0):

Try additional document state check, after IE state check:

```
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: i tried and the same error. I am getting Object Required getElementByID("...")

Comment: i have even put a sleep for 7 secs, but still the same error